# Get a jQuery element for a DOMElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I know how to do the opposite. Getting a certain DOMElement for a jQuery element is easy. (Use the get() method)

But how can you get a jQuery element for a specific DOMElement?

Unfortunately this DOMElement does not have any attributes like class or id so constructing a selector is not really an option.
Lets say I have this html:

```
<div class="edit">Abcd<b><i><u>asdasd</u>adasda</i></b>sdfsdf<br>asd</div>
```

I am in the u-DomElement. How can I get this as a jQuery element?

Is there a smart way to do this?

**EDIT:**

I wanted to know if there is a gerneral way to do this. Not specific to the code shown above.
Like:

```
DomElement.toJQuery()
```

Is there anything like that? I am aware that this might not be possible.

Comment: In the above example you would simply use `$(".edit u")`

Comment: Free [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zyykS/)

Comment: Archer, never use those child selectors.. these make your script slow. because jquery will search trough every <u>. In stead use: $(".edit").find("u");

Comment: @alex23 It will return a jQuery object that holds a collection of elements. `NodeList` is returned by methods like `getElementsByTagName` or `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: @ChrisVisser It will only search for `u` tags *inside* elements with a class of `edit` - it won't look at all `u` tags :)

Comment: No it does'nt jquery and CSS selectors work from right to left. It first searches for <u> tags and it then  searches for <u> tags that are children of .edit.

Comment: @ChrisVisser do you have any links to prove that this is the case in jquery? I always thought `$('.edit u')` is basically the same as `$('.edit').find('u')`.

Comment: @ChrisVisser Just created a comparison, find is like 90% (Chrome) slower than the css selectors.There we go: http://jsperf.com/find-vs-css-selector

Comment: See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-element

Comment: @Archer
http://24ways.org/2011/your-jquery-now-with-less-suck/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting a jQuery object for a DOM object is as simple as `jQuery(dom_node)` (or `$(dom_node)`).  See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

This is commonly used in event handlers, which are given the DOM node as `this`, so that you will often see `$(this)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get just the Element use the below code. if you wanted to get the HTML of any element you might want to add the [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) tag to either of the examples

```
var myVar = $('.edit u');
```

or

```
var myVar =  $(".edit").find("u");
```

Comment: He doesn't want the html ?confused?

Comment: I amended my answer, now i gave the example of how to get the element and the html if he ever wants to do so, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
$(".edit").find("u");
```

---

hope this is what you are looking for,

```
$(DomElement)
```

Comment: To get the dom version use this with as follows:
var $el = $(".edit").find("u");
var el = $el[0];

Comment: Thanks the $(DomElement) was what I was looking for. By now I also found a freind who had the same answer for me. Tahnks a lot. :)

Comment: so you accept the friend's answer and not the first answer. ;)

Answer (score -1):

you want a only 1 specific dom element i suggest you find a way to add an id to that element.

but to get an `u` element inside a `edit` class:

```
$('.edit u');

$('.edit').find('u');
```

Comment: Same as I posted above. Never do a query on just the tag. In stead use a selector to match an ID (best) or class (second option). Then use find to search for tags within that ID or class. Its much faster in the long run.